# Source files can't find React in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-app-rewired

[After getting this error](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning) I went through all the fixes listed on the page and landed on us having two or more copies of react. After looking through [this page](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991) and finding no applicable solutions I found react-app-rewired and tried to see if I could make it work. After putting this code into the config override file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = { 
  webpack(config) {
    config.resolve.alias['react']
      = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react');
      
    return config;
  }
};
```

[I got this error when I started the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM8O6.png)

Every file that imports react throws this error because it can't be imported.

This is an example of the imports for one of the files that throws an error

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './my-sass.scss'
    import './App.css';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router , Routes, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
    import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
    import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
    import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
    import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
    import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
```

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
```

I am very much a newbie with react and web development in general, so I have been trying to learn about sym-linking. I have no trouble finding the react folder, but I can't find anything to link it to. But I don't even know if symlinking is the right move here.

Comment: What do you mean by: "to solve the issue of having two or more copies of react"? You should only use rewired if you *really* need to change the webpack config.

Comment: I need to use the useRef hook and I used to [run into this error](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning), I couldn't find any other good solution for CRA, but now I have this error so maybe rewired wasn't the right move

Comment: This error has absolutely nothing to do with CRA or webpack, it tells you you can only use hooks in function components, and it's clearly explained on this page how to fix it.

Comment: I triple-checked that I did everything right with the hook but it still didn't work, which only left duplicate reacts and as I was researching fixes for that, I eventually found rewired

Comment: Even *if* it is the problem (I hope you did the debug steps to come to this conclusion), there is no need to twick the webpack config, just clean up your dependencies or do what the doc tells you (it doesn't tell you to link anything).

Comment: The doc doesn't have any solutions beside the github thread which I've already skimmed through. I've ran through everything the doc went over multiple times, I checked the dependencies and they look fine as well. I came to rewired because the way I see it I'm kind of out of options besides just starting over and copying over all the code

Comment: Have the debug steps actually shown that you have a problem of duplicate?

Comment: Yep, the debug steps do show this, alongside the fact that I've been able to rule out the other two options (with thorough testing)

Comment: Please edit your question to share the actual error you try to solve, the code throwing this error as well as what you tried to fix it. In short all what you said in comments plus the code. I think your current question lacks too much context.

Comment: I wanted to see the actual component, but in the imports you have `Component`, so you have a class component and not a function component, which is exactly why the error tells you you can't use a hook...

Comment: I've added another example, the file which originally threw the error of having multiple copies of react, which also throws the current error of having trouble with imports.

Comment: It's alright. But I'm wondering if you are not confused by the error and just don't realise you are trying to use a hook on a class component.

Comment: I mean I've tried hooks in normal functioning apps separate from this one and they work perfectly, doing the same here throws an error. And same as in copy paste into a new file

Comment: But did you get this error before trying to use a hook? I don't think I can't help you anymore with what you provided, a repo would be helpful.

Comment: No, this error first cropped up when I first tried to use a hook, which is why I have no idea where the other react came from, it could have been months ago. I'm leaning towards just copying over everything to a working app without duplicate reacts right now, I'll see if my groupmembers have any last minute ideas